# How to find if a geo-location is on a road between two points?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am a student working on an android application related to navigation trying to learn android programming. The application needs to search the geo-locations (latitude,longitude) among the ones available and find out which ones fall along the route the user is travelling.

For example, if the user is travelling from 37.422,-122.084058 to 37.422,-122.084058, then I should be able to search the points that fall along this route from the set of points that I have. How do I do that?

I am getting the route direction of the user from the google api

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Googleplex&destination=infinityloop=&key=your_api_key
```

I get the route in the form of legs and I have a set of geo-locations. I would like to find which geo-locations fall along the route of the user. Is there any way I can find it or any API that I can use ?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There's already a lib for this: use [isLocationOnPath](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath(LatLng,%20java.util.List,%20boolean)) with the `polyline` you are getting from directions api response.

Answer (score -1):

Build a [LatLngBound](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html) using the two points and pass in the geolocation point you want to check into [LatLngBounds.contain()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html#contains(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)).

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the answer. I tried working with LatLngBounds but it dosent work in all the cases. It works only if the route is build from northeast to southwest. I have tried to use this for various possible combinations of routes using latlng points but I am unable to get correct results in all cases.

Comment: Wrong result in the case of SE to NW and error in the case of NE to SW and NW to SE. Is there any way I can get the LatLngBounds working for all the cases ?