# Check if a given latitude, longitude point lies along the route from A to B

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am working with and android app and I need to find out if a given latitude,longitude point lies along the route from A to B.

I am using [LatLngBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html) for this. It works when the route is from SouthWest to NothEast only but never works for other routes (NE to SW or SE to NW or NW to SE). It gives wrong result for NW to SW and error for SE to NW or NW to SE.

I tried using [LtLngBounds.Builder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.Builder.html) for the other three cases i.e, NE to SW or SE to NW or NW to SE. But the code didnot work for them. Following is the code I used.

```
LatLngBounds.Builder b_builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
b_builder.include(se_latlng); //start point
b_builder.include(nw_latlng); //end point 
LatLngBounds b = b_builder.build(); //I am building the bound here
boolean present3 = b.contains(mid_latlng1); //Checking if this point lies along the route
boolean present4 = b.contains(mid_latlng2); //Checking if this point lies along the route
```

Both the above cases, I was getting true for b.contains(NE to SW or SE to NW or NW to SE). But in fact only one  among those points lies along the route. I tried the same for rest of the cases but I was getting true always even if the point lies or dosent lie along the route.

the LatLngBounds works for SouthWest to NorthEast though. Can anyone kindly help me find out if a point lies along the route from A to B in the other directions (NE to SW or SE to NW or NW to SE).

Comment: The builder's job is to construct a bounding box that includes all points provided to it, so I don't see how it can possibly provide any information about routes or directions. Calling contains will only tell you if a given point lies inside that generated boundary. From the names of your variables mid_latlng1 and mid_latlng2, I assume their coordinates lie at the center of the bounding rectangle generated using se_latlng and nw_latlng, so it makes sense that the contains method always returns true.

Comment: @stkent: Thanks for the clarification, I was following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908658/how-to-find-if-a-geo-location-is-on-a-road-between-two-points/28909591#28909591) to find if a given point lies on the route from point A to point B.  In the above problem, the se_latlng, nw_latlng are two points on a freeway. mid_latlng1 is a point in between them, on the freeway but not the exact mid point. mid_latlng2 is a point which might lie inside the bound rectangle, but is not on the freeway. It is a bit away from the freeway on another road.

Comment: It seems to me that using a LatLngBounds test for this problem is too coarse/inaccurate. If I were you, I would think about a geometric approach (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line for some discussion that is relevant). You should define some tolerance that represents a point being "close enough" to a straight line joining A to B. If you need fancier paths, you can break a path into straight lines and then reapply this same algorithm to each segment of the path.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lib for that task already. Creare a `Polyline` out of your `LatLng`'s and use [isLocationOnPath](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath(LatLng,%20java.util.List,%20boolean)).